# changing span to text with javascript using textcontent

Tags: javascript, html

I created an empty span within p tags which is supposed to change and reveal text when the button is clicked (button id="clickme"). Here is what I have tried (comments show other attempts):

```js
function writeNewMessage() {
   var newMessage = "hello";
   document.getElementById("spanMessage").innerHTML = newMessage;

   //document.getElementById("spanMessage").textContent="You have now finished Task 1";
   //var newMessage = document.getElementById("spanMessage");
   //newMessage.textContent = "You have now finished Task 1";
}
```

```js
function init() {
   var clickMe = document.getElementById("clickme");
   clickMe.onclick = promptName, writeNewMessage;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!--js--> <script src="io.js"></script> 
      <title>Click me</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Input and Output using Javascript</h1>
      <p id="message">This is some text in a paragraph</p>
      <p><span id="spanMessage"></span></p>
      <p><button type="button" id="clickme">Click me!</button></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there just a single `span` that you are targeting? It would be useful to see the HTML

Comment: html is: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--js-->
        <script src="io.js"></script>
    <title>Click me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Input and Output using Javascript</h1>
    <p id="message">This is some text in a paragraph</p>
    <p><span id="spanMessage"></span></p>
    <p><button type="button" id="clickme">Click me!</button></p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Are you trying to show/hide the text?

Comment: @BrookeJohnson Do you want to show/hide the span?

Comment: trying to change the blank span into new text mentioned in javascript. this should appear after button is clicked

Comment: In the above code you have not invoked the `init` function

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually invoke the `init` function to register the event handlers

```js
function writeNewMessage() {
    var newMessage = "hello";
    document.getElementById("spanMessage").innerHTML = newMessage;
}

function init() {
    document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener('click',writeNewMessage)
}

init();
```

```html
<h1>Input and Output using Javascript</h1>
<p id="message">This is some text in a paragraph</p>
<p><span id="spanMessage"></span></p>
<p><button id='clickme' type="button">Click me!</button></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invole the `init` function and you can set the text with `textContent`.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#clickme");
const spanMessage = document.querySelector("span#spanMessage");

function init() {
  button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    var newMessage = "hello";
    spanMessage.textContent = newMessage;
  });
}

init();
```

```html
<h1>Input and Output using Javascript</h1>
<p id="message">This is some text in a paragraph</p>
<p><span id="spanMessage"></span></p>
<p><button type="button" id="clickme">Click me!</button></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add onclick() function to the button.

```js
function writeNewMessage() {
    var newMessage = "hello message text";
    document.getElementById("spanMessage").innerHTML = newMessage;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!--js--> <script src="io.js"></script> 
      <title>Click me</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Input and Output using Javascript</h1>
      <p id="message">This is some text in a paragraph</p>
      <p><span id="spanMessage"></span></p>
      <p><button type="button" id="clickme" onclick="writeNewMessage()">Click me!</button></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must avoid overusing the `var` keyword in order to avoid populating the global namespace. You should use `const` and encapsulate them within the function. If you prefer, you can use an Event Bus system:

```js
// Event Bus Architecture
window.addEventListener('click', EventBus.bind(this));

function EventBus(event) {
    event.path[0].id === "clickme" ? Register() : null;
}

function Register() {
    const span = document.getElementById("spanMessage")
    span.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```